# How do I get/catch response status code from get API

Tags: angularjs

Below is the code

```
UserService.api.getProfile({userLogin: $scope.login}, function(res) {
            _.each($scope.visibility, function(e) {
                e.visible = (_.find(res, { 'roleName': e.name })) ? true : false;
            });
        });
```

And for userService.api.getProfile will be as below

```
angular.module('frontendApp').factory('UserService', [
'$resource',
function($resource) {
    return {
        api: $resource('service/authority-roles/:roleId', {}, {
            getProfile: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'service/user/:userLogin/authority-roles',
                isArray: true
            }
```

It works well if the API is sending response 200. However, when the API returns the response 404, the code unable to catch the status.

I tried using "Try" and "Catch" but it's not working. I also did console.log on res.status to get the status code but the value is undefined.

The plan is, if the API returning 400 response, then alert "User Not Found" message.

Appreciate your help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to see the implementation of `UserService.api.getProfile()` before we could tell, but my guess is that there is a third parameter which takes the failure callback function.

Comment: Hi @JacobStamm I have included getProfile above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any global `$http` interceptors that will handle this, you can do this on a per-api method basis by [specifying an `interceptor` object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#$resource-arguments) on your `getProfile` action, like so:

```js
getProfile: {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'service/user/:userLogin/authority-roles',
  isArray: true,
  interceptor: {
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about interceptors [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Comment: It works!!! thank you so much, this is very helpful. Will understand further on interceptors